# how to cp syslog to other places when install OS using preseed before reboot ubuntu16.04

Tags: server, system-installation, preseed, preferences

how to cp syslog to other places when install OS using preseed before reboot ubuntu16.04

I am trying to install an server version ubuntu 16.04 with preseed 
the whole proceed is quick and it takes less 10 min,
I want to read the logfile /var/log/syslog slowly.
any idea?

when install ,I can atl+f2 to get a shell and read the log /var/log/syslog for install details

but when the install is over,the os auto reboot,then the install logs disappears and log turns into boot logs

if any error and pause, maybe I can choose to setup a webserver on the menu and get the logs with chrome using download,but if the install is normal,I donot get the chance to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I find the install log in /var/log/installer/syslog after install reboot

and other install logs is here /var/log/installer/

So I consider it addressed and close the issue.